Renci.SshNet encountered a 'Permission denied (publickey)' error when using the user certificate with RSA SHA256
I'm using SSH.NET version 2024.0.0, but I cannot connect to an Ubuntu machine using OpenSSH server with a user certificate. However, I can connect using the command ssh -i user-key username@host in PowerShell:

Does anyone have a problem like mine? thanks
private key format
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----

This is the error I have encountered

Permission denied (publickey).

This is my code
byte[] content = Convert.FromBase64String(certFile);
var privateKeyFile = new PrivateKeyFile(new MemoryStream(content), passphrase);
PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod privateKeyAuthentication = new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod(username, privateKeyFile);

var keybAuth = new KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod(username);
keybAuth.AuthenticationPrompt +=
    delegate (object sender, AuthenticationPromptEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Prompts.Count() != 1) ||
            (e.Prompts.First().Request != "Verification code:"))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unexpected auth prompt");
        }
        e.Prompts.First().Response = "verification code";
    };
const conn = ConnectionInfo(host, port, username, privateKeyAuthentication, keybAuth)
{
    Timeout = 5000,
    RetryAttempts = 2,
    MaxSessions = 20
};
using (var ssh = new SshClient(conn)) 
{
    ssh.Connect();
    ...
}


SSH.NET does not support certificates.
See https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/issues/479
(there's a link to SSH.NET fork with certificates support though).
Related: .NET SSH with certificate authentication

If you do not want to use the mentioned SSH.NET fork, you will have to use another SSH library. There are not many.
My WinSCP .NET assembly does support certificates – If you can cope with its limitations (it's not native .NET assembly and runs on Windows only).
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library
